# Count how many times the datetime interval crosses the 08:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a 08:00 census that will capture any people that are in a room at 08:00 according to their start and end datetime.

I have a start datetime and eventually an end datetime but I need to show the next days date when no there is no end datetime.

If the start datetime is
***<= 08:00***
***and the end datetime is on the same day***
then this will be 1 otherwise it will not be displayed.

If the end datetime
***is not null and any day after the start datetime***
then this will be 1 on the next days until the end datetime.
But the final end datetime must be >= 08:00 or it wont be displayed for that day.

If the end datetime
***is null and any day after the start datetime***
then this will be 1 on the next days until the end datetime or the current day.
But the final end datetime must be >= 08:00 or it wont be displayed for that day.

If have shown a reference column in the data below to show how the rows will be displayed in the output table.  This won’t be included in the output.

e.g. Currentdate = 2016-11-30 11:00:00.000

**DATA**

```
Ref     Start                      End                          
1       2016-11-26 08:02:00.000    2016-11-26 09:00:00.000
2       2016-11-27 08:00:00.000    2016-11-28 07:00:00.000
3       2016-11-27 08:05:00.000    2016-11-28 11:00:00.000
4       2016-11-28 07:00:00.000    2016-11-29 11:00:00.000  
5       2016-11-28 08:45:00.000    2016-11-29 06:30:00.000
6       2016-11-25 09:00:00.000    null
```

**OUTPUT**

```
REF    Date          Num 
2      2016-11-27    1 
3      2016-11-28    1
4      2016-11-28    1
4      2016-11-29    1
6      2016-11-26    1
6      2016-11-27    1
6      2016-11-28    1
6      2016-11-29    1
6      2016-11-30    1  

1 and 5 are not displayed because of the criteria
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included in the result below all intermediary calculations to illustrate how it works.

The idea is to shift original timestamps by -8 hours at first (`ShiftedStartDT`, `ShiftedEndDT`).

Then you can calculate the number of days between them using simple `DATEDIFF` (`DiffDays`).

You need to check if the start timestamp is exactly at 08:00 and adjust results by +- 1 (`DiffAdjustment`).

Those rows that never cross `08:00` boundary have 0 `DiffDays`, so they can be filtered out in the `WHERE` clause.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Ref int, StartDT datetime2(0), EndDT datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO @T(Ref, StartDT, EndDT) VALUES
(1, '2016-11-26 08:02:00', '2016-11-26 09:00:00'),
(2, '2016-11-27 08:00:00', '2016-11-28 07:00:00'),
(3, '2016-11-27 08:05:00', '2016-11-28 11:00:00'),
(4, '2016-11-28 07:00:00', '2016-11-29 11:00:00'),
(5, '2016-11-28 08:45:00', '2016-11-29 06:30:00'),
(6, '2016-11-25 09:00:00', NULL);
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @CurrentDT datetime2(0) = '2016-11-30 11:00:00';
SELECT
    Ref
    ,NewStartDT
    ,DiffDays
    ,StartDT
    ,EndDT
    ,ShiftedStartDT
    ,ShiftedEndDT
    ,DiffAdjustment
FROM
    @T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, -8, StartDT) AS ShiftedStartDT
            ,DATEADD(hour, -8, ISNULL(EndDT, @CurrentDT)) AS ShiftedEndDT
    ) AS Shifted
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN ShiftedStartDT = CAST(ShiftedStartDT as date)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DiffAdjustment
    ) AS Adj
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(day, ShiftedStartDT, ShiftedEndDT) 
            + DiffAdjustment AS DiffDays
    ) AS Diff
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(day, 1-DiffAdjustment, CAST(ShiftedStartDT as date)) AS NewStartDT
    ) AS NewStart
WHERE
    DiffDays > 0
;
```

**Result**

```
+-----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| Ref | NewStartDT | DiffDays |       StartDT       |        EndDT        |   ShiftedStartDT    |    ShiftedEndDT     | DiffAdjustment |
+-----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|   2 | 2016-11-27 |        1 | 2016-11-27 08:00:00 | 2016-11-28 07:00:00 | 2016-11-27 00:00:00 | 2016-11-27 23:00:00 |              1 |
|   3 | 2016-11-28 |        1 | 2016-11-27 08:05:00 | 2016-11-28 11:00:00 | 2016-11-27 00:05:00 | 2016-11-28 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   4 | 2016-11-28 |        2 | 2016-11-28 07:00:00 | 2016-11-29 11:00:00 | 2016-11-27 23:00:00 | 2016-11-29 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-26 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
+-----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

---

If you really need to have 2 rows for `Ref=4` and 6 rows for `Ref=6`, you can do it by joining this result with a table of numbers.

In my database I have a table called `Numbers` that has a `int` column called `Number` with values from 1 to 100,000. It is useful in many queries and it can be used in this query like this:

```
SELECT
    Ref
    ,NewStartDT
    ,Num
    ,DiffDays
    ,StartDT
    ,EndDT
    ,ShiftedStartDT
    ,ShiftedEndDT
    ,DiffAdjustment
FROM
    @T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, -8, StartDT) AS ShiftedStartDT
            ,DATEADD(hour, -8, ISNULL(EndDT, @CurrentDT)) AS ShiftedEndDT
    ) AS Shifted
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN ShiftedStartDT = CAST(ShiftedStartDT as date)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DiffAdjustment
    ) AS Adj
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(day, ShiftedStartDT, ShiftedEndDT) 
            + DiffAdjustment AS DiffDays
    ) AS Diff
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(day, 1-DiffAdjustment, CAST(ShiftedStartDT as date)) AS BaseStartDT
    ) AS NewStart
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            1 AS Num
            ,DATEADD(day, dbo.Numbers.Number-1, BaseStartDT) AS NewStartDT
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        WHERE dbo.Numbers.Number <= DiffDays
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY Ref, NewStartDT;
```

**Result**

```
+-----+------------+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| Ref | NewStartDT | Num | DiffDays |       StartDT       |        EndDT        |   ShiftedStartDT    |    ShiftedEndDT     | DiffAdjustment |
+-----+------------+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|   2 | 2016-11-27 |   1 |        1 | 2016-11-27 08:00:00 | 2016-11-28 07:00:00 | 2016-11-27 00:00:00 | 2016-11-27 23:00:00 |              1 |
|   3 | 2016-11-28 |   1 |        1 | 2016-11-27 08:05:00 | 2016-11-28 11:00:00 | 2016-11-27 00:05:00 | 2016-11-28 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   4 | 2016-11-28 |   1 |        2 | 2016-11-28 07:00:00 | 2016-11-29 11:00:00 | 2016-11-27 23:00:00 | 2016-11-29 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   4 | 2016-11-29 |   1 |        2 | 2016-11-28 07:00:00 | 2016-11-29 11:00:00 | 2016-11-27 23:00:00 | 2016-11-29 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-26 |   1 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-27 |   1 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-28 |   1 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-29 |   1 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
|   6 | 2016-11-30 |   1 |        5 | 2016-11-25 09:00:00 | NULL                | 2016-11-25 01:00:00 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00 |              0 |
+-----+------------+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'll look at this straight away.

Comment: That is brilliant.  Thank you for that.  But as you stated I do need to a row for each day where it crosses 08:00.  I have excluded Ref from the data as I just included this to match up the data to the output table

Comment: @Mally, I added a second variant that uses a table of numbers to generate multiple rows per `Ref` as needed.

Comment: Thank you again.  That's brill.  The only other thing, which is shown in my example output was to display the date for the next day.  So for example, using Ref 6 in your table it would display as 2016-11-26, 2016-11-27, 2016-11-28, 2016-11-29 etc.

Comment: @Mally, yes, sorry, I forgot about that. Just add the `Number` to that base date. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you kindly for all of your help.  Exactly what I needed. Would have took me about 10 years to figure this out.